# Form doesn't validate

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a problem with form validation. Why this example doesn't work?

### HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <label>Repeat password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="repeat" placeholder="Password repeat" />
    <label></label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Create" />
</form>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').validate({
        rules:
        {
            email: { required: true }
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EJ2kd/2/)

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: do you have the plugin? http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js

Comment: Have you add form.js and validation.js ??

Comment: Doesnt work is just not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add the script/plugin for jQuery `.validate()`

Check [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/cSrqp/)

I used your fiddle and just added: `http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js`